# IIS 8 SSL Different IP with same ports. Website cannot be started

Tags: iis-8

We're running into an issue in IIS where we have 1 site started (http), with a binding of * on 10.xx.x.28:8082 (http). We have a second site, but this one is https with a different IP, binding is * on 10.xx.x.35:8082 (https).

When we try to start the https site, we are getting "This website cannot be started. Another website may be using the same port."

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: How have you assigned two IP addresses to the same computer? Have you bound both to the same certificate?

Comment: Only the https binding has the certificate.  The other IP is http.

Comment: Check the definitions of the websites. I suspect they are not as simple as stated. You will need to add screenshots of the settings to the post.

Comment: If I have both IP's set as http with the same port the sites start just fine.  But as soon as I change one of the IP's to https and assign the certificate the problem arises.  I'm not sure if it's a certificate issue, or just the fact that if we have 2 IPs going through the same port with one being http and the other https causes the issue.

Comment: I've added a screenshot above, as soon as I make those ports the same I run into the issue.

Comment: They are different services and should be on different ports.